# can't start minio in ubuntu due to "Variable MINIO_VOLUMES not set in /etc/default/minio";

Tags: minio

I am installing latest minio on ubuntu 18.04 following the minio installation instruction from [here](https://min.io/docs/minio/linux/operations/install-deploy-manage/deploy-minio-single-node-single-drive.html).

after the installation, try to run it with `sudo systemctl start minio.service`

but it didn't work with message.

```
...skipping...
● minio.service - MinIO
   Loaded: loaded (/etc/systemd/system/minio.service; disabled; vendor preset: enabled)
   Active: failed (Result: exit-code) since Thu 2022-12-08 17:03:45 CST; 2min 1s ago
     Docs: https://docs.min.io
  Process: 5072 ExecStart=/usr/local/bin/minio server $MINIO_OPTS $MINIO_VOLUMES (code=exited, status=1/FAILURE)
  Process: 5050 ExecStartPre=/bin/bash -c if [ -z "${MINIO_VOLUMES}" ]; then echo "Variable MINIO_VOLUMES not set in /etc/default/minio"; exit 1; fi (code=exited, status=0/SUCCES
 Main PID: 5072 (code=exited, status=1/FAILURE)

12月 08 17:03:45 nky systemd[1]: minio.service: Service hold-off time over, scheduling restart.
12月 08 17:03:45 nky systemd[1]: minio.service: Scheduled restart job, restart counter is at 5.
12月 08 17:03:45 nky systemd[1]: Stopped MinIO.
12月 08 17:03:45 nky systemd[1]: minio.service: Start request repeated too quickly.
12月 08 17:03:45 nky systemd[1]: minio.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.
12月 08 17:03:45 nky systemd[1]: Failed to start MinIO.
```

it is noted something wrong with 'MINIO_VOLUMES', but I have set the variable in the /etc/default/minio

```
MINIO_ROOT_USER=myminioadmin
MINIO_ROOT_PASSWORD=minio-secret-key-change-me
# MINIO_VOLUMES sets the storage volume or path to use for the MinIO server.
MINIO_VOLUMES="/mnt/data"
```

what is wrong with my configuration?

Answer (score 0):

There is nothing obvious wrong with your configuration but you did not post your service file. Almost always this is a permissions issue, you can change the systemd service user to `root` to test. Common issues after that are that the binary is not present in the location specified in the service file, or not executable.

Comment: I have tried  sudo systemctl start minio, still the same error. however trying  sudo minio server /mnt/data works.

Comment: Well, again without the config requested it is impossible to say. But, since you say it works outside of systemd, it does point to permissions issue